# Error using OIDC with Atlassian bitbucket and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use OIDC with a role and a web identity on aws. I followed the steps from https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-on-aws-using-bitbucket-pipelines-openid-connect/

As noted at the end of the post, the OIDC works when I use atlassian pipes but it does not work with the export and aws cli options.

```
  default:
    - step:
        name: Connect to AWS using OIDC
        oidc: true
        script:
          - export AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION
          - export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole
          - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
          - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token
          - printenv BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN
          - printenv AWS_REGION
          - printenv AWS_ROLE_ARN
          - aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity --role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole --role-session-name build-session --web-identity-token "$BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN" --duration-seconds 1000
```

PrintEnv Output:

```
printenv AWS_REGION
us-east-2

printenv AWS_ROLE_ARN
arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole

printenv BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN
<nothing here>
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

However when I use a pipe then everything works fine

```
  - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:1.1.0
    variables:
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION # Optional if already defined in the context or OIDC used.
      AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN: $AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN # Optional by default. Required for OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication.
      S3_BUCKET: mygreat-bucket
      LOCAL_PATH: 'build'
      CACHE_CONTROL: 'max-age=86400'
```

Comment: Beware that you may need to use `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and not AWS_REGION

Comment: Also note the `export AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION` instruction is totally useless, as the variable is already in the environment.

Comment: I have setup a bitbucket repository variable called AWS_REGION. the problem is not with the region as it works when I use the pipes.

Comment: What aws-cli version are you using? I'll usually run the whole pipeline step with `image: amazon/aws-cli`. Usually they are deployment steps, so no specific language runtimes are needed, and that image is fine. Can you use it?

Comment: I am using `image: amazon/aws-cli` as you mentioned.

Comment: Are you running the pipe in a step marked with `deployment: test|production|whatever` but the aws sts command in a regular step? Could you swap them to test if this is the root of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled into the same thing - BitBucket pipes works with AWS OIDC out of the box but scripts does not. If you check particular pipe source code you will find there are few extra steps needed to assume the role - https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-s3-deploy/src/master/pipe/pipe.sh#lines-35

So to make script section working with OIDC you need to have it like this:

```
default:
- step:
    name: Connect to AWS using OIDC
    oidc: true
    script:
      - export AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION
      - export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole
      - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
      - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token
      - aws configure set web_identity_token_file ${AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE}
      - aws configure set role_arn ${AWS_ROLE_ARN}
      - unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - printenv BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN
      - printenv AWS_REGION
      - printenv AWS_ROLE_ARN
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, exporting those env variables is enough and you shouldn't need further sts assume-role-with-web-identity commands.

Just try

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Test OIDC
        oidc: true
        image: public.ecr.aws/aws-cli/aws-cli
        script:
          - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=my-region-0
          - export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyRole
          - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
          - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
          - aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: I have tried that and it failed too.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar situation. I wanted to run aws cli commands inside a script using the AWS OIDC IAM role. Seems keeping `oidc:true` is not sufficient to authenticate to AWS.

So as a workaround to make OIDC work on the scripts, I used the sts assume-role command to get the temporary credentials and using the `jq` linux tool to parse the response and use it to configure aws cli.

```
default:
  - step
      name: Configure AWS CLI
      oidc: true
      script:
        - assume_role_response=$(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myRole --role-session-name build-session  --web-identity-token "$BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN" --duration-seconds 1000)
        - access_key_id=$(echo "$assume_role_response" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
        - secret_access_key=$(echo "$assume_role_response" | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
        - session_token=$(echo "$assume_role_response" | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')
        - aws configure set aws_access_key_id "$access_key_id"
        - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "$secret_access_key"
        - aws configure set aws_session_token "$session_token"
        - aws s3 ls
```

Not sure if there are other easier solutions out there, but this worked for me.